# process not starting completely, when called inside crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a script( let us call it **watcher**) which checks for a particular process if it's not running the watcher will start the process through a script.

I run this watcher in crontab at every minute. Now the problem is that it's not working in crontab but working if I run the watcher directly from the command line.

suppose the watcher start a script file called **serverA**.

**ServerA** code

```
echo -n "Starting $NAME: "

# start network server
start-stop-daemon --start --background --make-pidfile \
    --pidfile $net_server_pidfile --startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $angel $net_server \
    -c $conf_file --lora-eui $lora_eui --lora-hw-1 $lora_hw --lora-prod-1 $lora_id \
    --lora-path $run_dir --db $conf_db \
    --noconsole >> $net_server_log 2>&1"
sleep 2
# start packet forwarder
/usr/sbin/start-stop-daemon --chdir $run_dir/1 --start --background --make-pidfile \
    --pidfile $pkt_fwd_pidfile --exec $angel -- $pkt_fwd 

renice -n -20 -p $(pgrep lora-network-se)
renice -n -20 -p $(pgrep $(basename $pkt_fwd))

echo "OK"
```

Now if i run watcher from directly the serverA will echo output Starting something then after sometime it continues with OK at the end.

But in crontab logs i dont see the OK, because of which the service never completes and serverA never starts.

**watcher.sh**

```
else
              echo "$(date) do something, no packet forwader runnig"
              exec /etc/init.d/lora-network-server start

      fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to check difference of run time environments based terminal or not.

Firstly Check the lora-network-server whether depend on shell environments, such as JAVA_HOME or PATH (e.g. can execute the binary without absolute path of binary).

If it has different setting, it make same shell environments.

For exmaple, how to diff between cron env and runtime env.

**runtime**

```
$ env | tee ./runtime.output
```

**cron**

```
$ crontab <<EOF
* * * * * /bin/env > /path/to/cron.output 2>&1
EOF
```

Above cron output will create after 1 minute, and remove the cront after test.

you can check the variables onto cron.output and runtime.output

I hope this will help you.

Comment: how do i check the environment settings of serverA file?

Comment: Hi @Daein it says `/bin/sh: /bin/env: No such file or directory`

Comment: What OS you use? @ashusvirus

Comment: its linux 3.12.27r13

Comment: i just need to add /usr/sbin for the start-stop-daemon process. it looks like cron cant find the daemon.

Comment: I think you found your root cause of your issue, previous command env has alternatives, `printenv` , `set`, `export`

Comment: when i echo $PATH in cron script, i get only 2 paths.. i need same env var as i see in root. how to do that?

Comment: you can added the directive `export PATH=same your runtime env` into shell or cronttab with `PATH=same your runtime env`,  be careful when set up the PATH var into crontab, not need the `export`

Answer (score 0):

Cron runs with a mostly empty environment. Are you setting all necessary environment variables in your scripts?